# System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#

i am making a webmethod in asmx.... 
        but whenever i run this method i will get this error... 
           i want to add manually row in dataset,with the help of datareader
    [WebMethod]

```
public DataSet newleger(string accno, string fromdate, string todate)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=123-PC;Initial Catalog=bcounts;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Saba;Password=123");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select gt.Value_Date,gt.Voucher_no+'-'+gr.VchrType as voucher,gt.Acct_Nirration,gr.InstrumentNo,gt.Dr_Amount,gt.Cr_Amount  from gl_transaction gt, Gl_Ref gr where gt.Accountno = '" + accno + "'  and gt.Voucher_No=gr.Voucher_no  and gt.Value_Date between '" + fromdate + "' and '" + todate + "'", con);
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    decimal crsum = 0;
    decimal drsum = 0;
    decimal balance = 0;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("Ledger");;
       adp.Fill(ds);
    if (rdr.HasRows)
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            if (rdr.GetDecimal(4) > 0)
            {
                balance = balance + rdr.GetDecimal(4);
                drsum += rdr.GetDecimal(4);
                DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
                dr[0] = rdr.GetDateTime(0).ToShortDateString();
                dr[1] = rdr.GetString(1);
                dr[2] = rdr.GetString(2);
                dr[3] = rdr.GetString(3);
                dr[4] = rdr.GetDecimal(4).ToString();
                dr[5] = "-";
                ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);

                //data.Add(new datalist7(rdr.GetDateTime(0).ToShortDateString(), rdr.GetString(1), rdr.GetString(2), rdr.GetString(3), rdr.GetDecimal(4).ToString(), "-", balance.ToString()));
            }
            else
            {
                balance = balance - rdr.GetDecimal(5);
                crsum += rdr.GetDecimal(5);
                DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
                dr[0] = rdr.GetDateTime(0).ToShortDateString();
                dr[1] = rdr.GetString(1);
                dr[2] = rdr.GetString(2);
                dr[3] = rdr.GetString(3);
                dr[4] = "-";
                dr[5] = rdr.GetDecimal(5).ToString();
                ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);

               // data.Add(new datalist7(rdr.GetDateTime(0).ToShortDateString(), rdr.GetString(1), rdr.GetString(2), rdr.GetString(3), "-", rdr.GetDecimal(5).ToString(), balance.ToString()));
            }
        }

        DataRow dd = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        dd[0] = "-";
        dd[1] = "-";
        dd[2] = "-";
        dd[3] = "-";
        dd[4] = drsum.ToString();
        dd[5] = crsum.ToString();
        //data.Add(new datalist7("-", "-", "-", "-", drsum.ToString(), crsum.ToString(), "-"));
    }
    con.Close();
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: try using a DataAdapter to read all the data first, into a DataSet/DataTable then do your aggregation and add a row.

Comment: My guess is you can't use the adapter and reader at the same time. Try closing one before you use the other.

Comment: how to use datadapter ??? give some code

Comment: You already have on in your code. After you call Fill it will populate your DataSet with the result of the SQL query. By using the reader you are doing double work. foreach the DataSet.Tables[0] you don't need the reader.

Comment: wat can i eliminate in this code???? kindly do help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public DataSet newleger(string accno, string fromdate, string todate)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=123-PC;Initial Catalog=bcounts;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Saba;Password=123");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select gt.Value_Date,gt.Voucher_no+'-'+gr.VchrType as voucher,gt.Acct_Nirration,gr.InstrumentNo,gt.Dr_Amount,gt.Cr_Amount  from gl_transaction gt, Gl_Ref gr where gt.Accountno = '" + accno + "'  and gt.Voucher_No=gr.Voucher_no  and gt.Value_Date between '" + fromdate + "' and '" + todate + "'", con);
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adp.SelectCommand = cmd;

    decimal crsum = 0;
    decimal drsum = 0;
    decimal balance = 0;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("Ledger");;
    adp.Fill(ds);

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        //do stuff here....
        if(Convert.ToDecimal(dr[4]) > 0)
        {
            balance = balance + Convert.ToDecimal(dr[4]);
            drsum += Convert.ToDecimal(dr[4]);
        }
        else
        {
             balance = balance - Convert.ToDecimal(dr[5]);
             crsum += Convert.ToDecimal(dr[5]);
        }
    }

    //add the totals
    DataRow dd = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
    //dd[0] = "-";
    //dd[1] = "-";
    //dd[2] = "-";
    //dd[3] = "-";
    dd[4] = drsum;
    dd[5] = crsum;
    //data.Add(new datalist7("-", "-", "-", "-", drsum.ToString(), crsum.ToString(), "-"));


    return ds;
}
```

Comment: what can i write instead of rdr??
dr[0] = rdr.GetDateTime(0).ToShortDateString();

Comment: Its already in your DataSet. Try setting a breakpoint and you can inspect the dataset and see a table view of the data. Your dataset is already populated when you call. SqlDataAdapter.Fill(). See my edits, it will probably run as it is now.

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
now i am getting this error

Comment: Whats your string look like?

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store &lt;-&gt; in Value_Date Column.  Expected type is DateTime. --->

Comment: Where do you get this error at in the code above? Need a line number.

Comment: Its your "-" stuff when you add the new rows. Those are DateTime columns now, you can't put "-" in them, just remove those instead.

Comment: dd[0] = "-"; in this line

Comment: then wat can i add instead of "-"?

Comment: if (Convert.ToDecimal(dr[4]) > 0)
        {
            balance = balance + Convert.ToDecimal(dr[4]);
            drsum += Convert.ToDecimal(dr[4]);
        }
        else
        {
            balance = balance - Convert.ToDecimal(dr[5]);
            crsum += Convert.ToDecimal(dr[5]);
        }
    }
  
    DataRow dd = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
    dd[0] = "";
    dd[1] = "";
    dd[2] = "";
    dd[3] = "";
    dd[4] = drsum.ToString();
    dd[5] = crsum.ToString();
   


    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dd);
   

    return ds;

Comment: See my edits, you don't need to populate those columns